# How to get GridView data selected in viewText of another activity

Tags: android, gridview

I saw this question's answers but they didn't solved mine . I have a `Gridview` containing pictures and strings I want when I select one of them the string has to be returned in another activity 
this is my first activity:

```
public class TypeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String selectedItem;

    private GridView type_grid;
    private String[] voiture_type ={"2 
            roues","Petit","Moyen","Grand","Haut","Très haut"
    };
    private int [] images={R.drawable.deuxroues,R.drawable.smallcar,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.grandvoiture,R.drawable.haut,R.drawable.car};

    private Button confirm ;
    public static DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();



    public static int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    public static int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type);
        confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_type);




        type_grid =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this,voiture_type,images);

        type_grid.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        type_grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();





            }
        });



        confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(com.example.macbookpro.tunipark.activity.TypeActivity.this,  Reservation.class);
                i.putExtra("typeValue",selectedItem.trim());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });




    }
}
```

and this is my `GridAdapter` code . and I called in the second activity my extra data but it can't be shown by this code. may someone have any idea

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    private final String[] voiture_type;
    private  final  int[] images;
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] voiture_type, int[] images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.voiture_type = voiture_type;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return voiture_type.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new View(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item,null);
            view.setMinimumHeight(TypeActivity.height/6);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.type_item);
            imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            textView.setText(voiture_type[position]);
        }
        return  view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **setOnItemClickListener** to get GridView selected item value

```
     type_grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              selectedItem = voiture_type[position];



            }
        });
```